# Allow page breaks inside tr and td elements

Tags: html, css, printing, html-table, page-break

I'm trying to create a one column table that allows a page break inside of `tr` and `td` cells. Below is just an example but my actual table has a lot going on inside of each cell.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>TABLE HEADER</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td><div class="my-cell">Hello World</div></td></tr>
    <tr><td><div class="my-cell">Hello World</div></td></tr>
    <tr><td><div class="my-cell">Hello World</div></td></tr>
    <tr><td><div class="my-cell">Hello World</div></td></tr>
    <tr><td><div class="my-cell">Hello World</div></td></tr>
    <tr><td><div class="my-cell">Hello World</div></td></tr>
    <tr><td><div class="my-cell">Hello World</div></td></tr>
    <tr><td><div class="my-cell">Hello World</div></td></tr>
    <tr><td><div class="my-cell">Hello World</div></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm using the following style to see where the cells start and end:

```
.my-cell {
  padding: 160px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

When I print this page, the table breaks after the second row to avoid splitting the third row:

[image]

My goal is to prevent this automatic page break. I've tried adding the following css, but it's still breaking at the same place:

```
tr, td {
  page-break-inside: initial;
}
```

Is there anyway to allow page breaks inside of `tr` and `td` elements or is this not possible? And where is this property actually set? It doesn't appear anywhere in chrome developer tools or in documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html#propdef-page-break-inside), the `page-break-inside` property applies to block elements although user agents could apply it to other elements:

> User Agents must apply these properties to block-level elements in the normal flow of the root element. User agents may also apply these properties to other elements, e.g., 'table-row' elements.

So one possibility (that may not be ideal) would be to change the display of the rows when printing so they are `display: block` instead of the default `display: table-row`. Something like this (this is too generic, you may need to make it more specific):

```
@media print {
    tr {
        page-break-inside: initial;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

I tested and it works fine on Chrome and Safari, but doesn't seem to work on Firefox:

[image: Printing dialog]

Answer (score 1):

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/

```
 page-break-inside : auto | avoid
```

Id figure Auto might help.

Comment: I applied this to tr and huzzah.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around with this for a while and eventually concluded that the cleanest solution would be to convert my table to `div`s with `flex` layout.

It looks somewhat like this:

*CSS*

```css
.table {
   display : flex;
   flex-direction : column;
}

.row {
   display : flex;
   flex-direction : row
}

.cell {
  border : 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin-right : -1px;
  margin-bottom : -1px;
  padding : 3px;
}

.col1 {
   width : 200px;
   flex-shrink : 0;
}

.col2 {
   width : 150px;
   flex-shrink : 0;
}

.col3 {
   width : 150px;
   flex : 1 1 auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="table">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col1 cell">Column 1</div>
      <div class="col2 cell">Column 2</div>
      <div class="col3 cell">Column 3</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col1 cell">Column 1</div>
      <div class="col2 cell">Column 2</div>
      <div class="col3 cell">Column 3</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

See working sample: https://jsfiddle.net/nqcf6x1g/1/